# HttpPostedFileBase doesn't get binded to model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, httppostedfilebase

I'm trying to upload an image with the [HttpPostedFileBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfilebase?view=netframework-4.8) class included in my view model. My code looks like the following

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("EditUserProfilePartial", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h3 class="text-center">@Model.Name</h3>
    <div class="w-100">
        <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle w-25 d-block" src="@Model.ProfilePicturePath" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, Resources.UserProfileEditUserProfileUserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control", required = "true", placeholder = Resources.UserProfileEditUserProfileUserName })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, Resources.UserProfileEditUserProfileUserEmail)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control", required = "true", placeholder = Resources.UserProfileEditUserProfileUserEmail })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProfilePicture, Resources.UserProfileEditUserProfileUserProfilePicture)
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input class="custom-file-input" type="file" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.ProfilePicture)" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.ProfilePicture)" placeholder="@Resources.UserProfileEditUserProfileUserProfilePicture" />
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProfilePicture, Resources.UserProfileEditUserProfileUserProfilePicture, new { @class = "custom-file-label" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and my view model

```
public class EditUserProfileViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicturePath { get; set; }
}
```

I've already searched for how to solve this but the solutions I found (mostly they forgot to add the enctype) don't work for me.

**EDIT**
What I found out and what is I suppose pretty interesting is that the file upload works when I call the action directly by entering the url in the browser. But when I append the form as a modal to the body by using ajax and [jquery modal](https://jquerymodal.com/) it doesn't

Comment: This can be because the default settings for the `jQuery.ajax` method. By default, the content type for the jQuery.ajax() method is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score -1):

Of course it wouldn't. You're not binding the value to anything.

update the input tag to something like this.

```
        <input class="custom-file-input" type="file" name="file" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.ProfilePicture)" placeholder="@Resources.UserProfileEditUserProfileUserProfilePicture" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
```

In this case your controller method should look like

```
EditUserProfilePartial(EditUserProfileViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

Comment: Doesn't work though. Also as far as I know you can bind directly to the model and that's what I did. See the name and id attribute of the input element.

Comment: This answer is rude, unhelpful and incorrect. As @nikstffrs points out, he **is** binding correctly using the Html Helper class. In future @JamesS, it would be helpful to exclude the vague sarcasm and instead explain the reasoning to your solution. If you did that you might notice that the link between the `name` attribute and `file` parameter shows the same relationship from the OP question